# Kendoui grid, datasource and restful service

Tags: kendo-ui

**Q1**: I'm trying to get the kendoui grid bound to a datasource talking to a restful service, (using servicestack).  All is working ok except when I call PUT and the rest service sends back the persisted poco object I get a strange javascript error and you do not get to the success method of the datasource.

Error is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number kendo.all.min.js:9
extend.setter kendo.all.min.js:9
o.extend._set kendo.all.min.js:9
T.extend.accept kendo.all.min.js:9
o.extend._accept kendo.all.min.js:9
(anonymous function) kendo.all.min.js:9
n jquery.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
o.fire jquery.min.js:2
g.(anonymous function).call.c.success kendo.all.min.js:9
n jquery.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
w jquery.min.js:4
d
```

The datasource/grid configuration looks like

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "/api/configuration/databaseconnections";
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
        read: {
            url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
            dataType: "json"
        },
        update: {
            url: function (db) {
            console.log(db);
            return crudServiceBaseUrl + "/" + db.Id;
            },
            type: "PUT",
            success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            }
            //dataType: "json"
        },
        destroy: {
            url: function (db) {
            return crudServiceBaseUrl + "/" + db.Id;
            },
            type: "DELETE",
            //dataType: "json"
        },
        create: {
            url: function (db) {
            return crudServiceBaseUrl + "/" + db.Id;
            },
            type: "PUT",
            //dataType: "json"
        },
        },




        schema: {
        model: {
                id: "Id",
            fields: {
            Id: { type: "string" },
            ConnectionString: { type: "string" },
            DatabaseType: { type: "string" },
            ProfileConnection: { type: "string" },
            }
        }
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: false,
        serverFiltering: false,
        serverSorting: false,
        model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
            ConnectionString: { editable: true },
            DatabaseType: { editable: false, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
            ProfileConnection: { editable: false, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
        }
        }

    },
    height: 250,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [{
        field: "Id",
        filterable: false,
        width: 150,
    },
        {
        field: "ConnectionString",
        title: "Connection String",
        filterable: false,
        }, {
        field: "DatabaseType",
        title: "Type",
        width: 100
        },
        {
        field: "ProfileConnection",
        title: "Profile",
        width: 100
        },
    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "210px" }
    ],
    editable: "popup"
    });
});
```

**Q2**: Anyone have an idea or a sample of the kendoui datasource working with a crud rest service ?

Comment: It turned out the error is because the data I was entering in the connection string text box has a ";" in it.  Going to look into how I can escape it correctly with kendoui.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**: As you mentioned in your comment you found the problem.( ";" in connection string)

**Q2**: But for second question, download and check this sample code ([Binding grid to a Web ApiController](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/binding-to-a-web-apicontroller.aspx)) it may help you or others refer here.